# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TwilioRestClient'

Tags: python, django, twilio

Trying to integrate django 1.10 application with twilio 6.0.0 and django-twilio==0.8.0

referring [link](http://blog.endpoint.com/2014/11/integrate-twilio-in-django.html)
showing Error in my shell..

```
7 def send_twilio_message(to_number, body):
----> 8     client = twilio.rest.TwilioRestClient(
      9         settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, settings.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
     10 

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TwilioRestClient'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated with the solution:
version twilio==6.0.0 (current one ) has different directory structure,so it effect importing structure
 Below is the updated importing structure ..

```
from django.conf import settings

import twilio
import twilio.rest

from twilio.rest import Client 

def send_twilio_message(to_number, body):
    client = Client(settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, settings.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)

    return client.api.account.messages.create(
        body=body,
        to=to_number,
        from_=settings.PHONE_NUMBER
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

The [tutorial](http://blog.endpoint.com/2014/11/integrate-twilio-in-django.html) you are following was written for an older version of the twilio sdk than 6.0.

You could try to look for a newer tutorial to follow, or you could try to adjust the tutorial. The [migration guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python/migration-guide) might help with this.

You final option is to install an older, unsupported version of the twilio library that works with the tutorial, e.g.

```
pip install twilio==5.7
```